# Subscribing to multiple topics of the same type

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to subscribe to multiple topics of the same type using a single callback function? If it's possible, I can't figure out how.

Please and thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56168/subscribing-to-multiple-topics-of-the-same-type./) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer (should work with regular messages as well):

```
SubscriberFilter leftsub = leftsub(it, "/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw", 1);
SubscriberFilter rightsub = rightsub(it, "/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw", 1);
TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync(leftsub, rightsub, 10);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&imagesub::callback, this, _1, _2));
void imagesub::callback(const ImageConstPtr& left, const ImageConstPtr& right) {
}
```

---

Originally posted by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) with karma: 172 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-03-01**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can easily do that by creating multiple subscribers or a vector of subscribers and make all of them point at same callback function.

```
  sicklms_subs = new ros::Subscriber[no_of_ugv];
    for(int i = 0; i < no_of_ugv; i++)
    {
        ss.seekp(0);
        ss << "/sicklms" << i << "/scan";
        sicklms_subs[i] = nh.subscribe(ss.str(), 100, &mapper_direct::laserCallback, this);
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on 2013-02-25**:
That works. But is it possible to accept multiple different topics of the same type in a single callback function?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-25**:
yeah it is possible to that. Every element of vector can be subscribed to a different message name and still can have same callback function. I hope this is what ur asking..

**Comment by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on 2013-02-25**:
It seems like I phrased my original question incorrectly, apologies for that. What I meant was, say I have to two subscribed topics, A and B. I want to process both A and B in a single callback function at the same time, for example A+B. Just wondering if that's possible.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-25**:
I think its not possible to do that...ROS does not provide a direct functionality for it so u have to write ur callback function in a way that provides you this functionality.

**Comment by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on 2013-02-26**:
Yeah I'm trying to figure that out. Thanks anyways :)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-02**:
Please edit your question to reflect what you want to know.